# Custom field doesn't show up in 'field type' dropdown

Tags: 7, entities

I've been trying to create a custom field for my module.  I have used the field_example module as a guide but my field doesn't show up in the 'field type' dropdown on the 'manage fields' page.

Here is my code:

**mantis.module**

```
function mantis_field_info() {
    return array(
        'mantisform' => array(
            'label' => 'Mantis ' . t('Form'),
            'description' => 'Mantis Support Request Form',
            'default_widget' => 'mantis_mantisform_widget',
            'default_formatter' => 'mantisform_default'
         )
    );
}

function mantis_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
    if($field['type'] == 'mantisform') {
        if(empty($field['mantis_form_id'])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function mantis_field_widget_info() {

    return array(
    'mantis_mantisform_widget' => array(
        'label' => 'Mantis ' . t('Form'),
        'field_types' => array('mantisform'),
        'behaviors' => array(
            'multiple_values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
            'default_value' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_NONE
            )
        )
    );
}

function mantis_field_widget_form($form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {

    $base = $element;

    if($instance['widget']['type'] == 'mantis_mantisform_widget') {
        $widget = $instance['settings'];
        $settings = $widget['settings'];

        $element['mantis_form_id'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => t('Support Request Form'),
            '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['mantis_form_id']) ? $items[$delta]['mantis_form_id'] : NULL
        );
    }
    return $element;
}

function mantis_field_formatter_info() {
    return array(
        'mantisform_default' => array(
            'label' => t('Default'),
            'description' => t('Allows a ') . 'mantis' . t('support form to be selected'),
            'field types' => array('mantisform'),
        )
    );
}

function mantis_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {

    $element = array();

    switch($display['type']) {
        case 'mantisform_default': {

        }
    }
    return $element;
}
```

**mantis.install**

```
function mantis_field_schema($field) {
    if($field['type'] == 'mantisform') {
        $schema['columns']['mantis_form_id'] = array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'not null' => false,
        );
        return $schema;
    }
}
```

I haven't completely fleshed out mantis_field_formatter_view but figured that I should still be able to see the new field as an option in the dropdown.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You cleared all caches?

Comment: Yeah, several times. Tried uninstalling the module and re-enabling it as well.

Comment: This does appear to have been a caching issue.  The field has appeared now. weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does appear to have been a caching issue. The field has appeared now. weird.